# error C2672 and C2784 when using lamdas with template functions

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I have written the following function which hides the loops when iterating over a 2d vector:

```
    template<typename ElementType>
    void iterateOver2DVector(std::vector<std::vector<ElementType>> & vec, 
                             std::function<void(ElementType & element)> function)
    {
        for(auto & row : vec)
        {
            for(auto & element : row)
            {
                function(element);
            }
        }
    }
```

but I get error:

```
'function': no matching overloaded function found
```

and

```
'declaration' : could not deduce template argument for 'type' from 'type'
```

when using it with lambdas like this:

```
iterateOver2DVector(graph, [](Node & node) { node.update(); } );
```

Does someone know what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call will try to deduce `ElementType` from both the first and second parameter/argument pair.

It will fail for the second pair, since the second argument to the function is not a `std::function`, but a closure type.

If it fails for one pair, then the whole deduction fails, even if the other pair would deduce the template argument for `ElementType` correctly.

Your function doesn't need to deduce `ElementType` from the second parameter/argument pair, so you can make it a *non-deduced context*, so that no deduction for it will be attempted.

A common approach to that is to use `std::type_identity_t`:

```
template<typename ElementType>
void iterateOver2DVector(std::vector<std::vector<ElementType>> & vec, 
                         std::type_identity_t<std::function<void(ElementType & element)>> function)
```

`std::type_identity_t<T>` is an alias for `std::type_identity<T>::type` which is an alias for `T`, however since the type `T` now is left of a `::` it is in a non-deduced context.

`std::type_identity_t` is only available since C++20, but it can be defined easily in previous versions of C++:

```
template<typename T> struct type_identity { using type = T; };
template<typename T> using type_identity_t = typename type_identity<T>::type;
```

---

However, in this case `std::function` is just unnecessary overhead anyway. Simply accept the closure type directly, instead of a `std::function`:

```
template<typename ElementType, typename F>
void iterateOver2DVector(std::vector<std::vector<ElementType>> & vec, 
                         F function)
```

A `std::function` is only useful if you intend to store the callable without dependence on its specific type e.g. in a class member and even in that case the conversion to `std::function` can be done when assigning to the member.